# Arduino mega 2560 does not connect via USB

Tags: 16.04, usb, serial-port, arduino

I dont know it this is the right place to ask this question, but I think there is enough know how here to solve my problem.

When I connect my arduino mega 2560 via USB, I get the following errormessage  on the "dmesg | tail" command:

```
$ dmesg | tail
[105846.261662] ch341 3-11:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[105846.263526] ch341-uart: probe of ttyUSB0 failed with error -71
[105890.572837] usb 3-11: USB disconnect, device number 31
[105890.573050] ch341 3-11:1.0: device disconnected
[105896.342699] usb 3-11: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[105896.471954] usb 3-11: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523
[105896.471957] usb 3-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[105896.471958] usb 3-11: Product: USB2.0-Serial
[105896.472453] ch341 3-11:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[105896.472565] ch341-uart: probe of ttyUSB0 failed with error -71
```

There can no serialport be selected in the arduino IDE. But when I connect my uno to my ubuntu 16.04 box, than a serialport appears.

I tested the mega on the windows laptop of my brother, and than I can upload. So my conclusion so far is that the problem is not a faulty arduino, if it does connect on a windows box. It should not be a permission problem because the uno does connect.

How should I start troubleshooting this? What does the errormessage exactly say?
Where does the problem originate?

Thanks!

Comment: Try plugging it in another port USB2 or Disable USB3 from the BIOS settings.

Comment: is this an original arduino 2560 or a cheap clone? i think it should create an ttyACM device instead of ttyUSB